# Ways to flush page cache without reboot?

Tags: linux, benchmarking

I am running a benchmark on Disk IO  + data compression, and the benchmark to be accurate has to include time from disk fetch. The issue being that once I compress a file once, I can't do a second accurate trial because the whole file is in working memory. Is there a way to flush the page cache without rebooting?

Comment: 1. [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87908/108618). 2. `man 8 vmtouch`, `-e` option.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Why don't you answer this?

Comment: @knowads: No emptying of buffers will ever reproduce the state of the OS after a cold boot. The hard disk may have its own cache that you cannot control.

Comment: @harrymc No time at the moment. Sharing knowledge by terse commenting, so anyone can investigate further and answer. If anyone bases an answer on my comment, I won't mind. No credit needed.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Take your time.

Comment: @harrymc that's fine. As long as I can reasonably demonstrate one type of disk + compression algorithm has significantly different performance when changing out the disk type or algorithm. The SSD + the algorithm are what is being evaluated, not the RAM module, hence why I'm trying to flush page cache.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand - if the file is fully or partially in the disk's cache, it will be transmitted to the RAM at channel speeds with no disk activity at all.

Comment: @harrymc oh I forgot about the SSD DRAM cache. Yeah that sucks, but even getting if from the SSD DRAM's cache is preferable to just main memory cause that's part of a "replaceable" component (which is the Disk unit itself) for this experiment.